# Query the database where colmns have similar data

Tags: sql, database

I have 20 columns with the same data. 
Dept_1, dept_2, dept_3....
I want to query the database, where each of these columns match (pseudocode: `where dept_1, dept_2, dept_3... = 'ACCOUNTING'`) without having to actually write out all 20 of these columns in the `WHERE` clause. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'd probably reconsider the design of the database. Without knowing more about what you're trying to do, @mellamokb's solution is probably best, even though your question seems to be more about getting around this serious design flaw.

Comment: I agree with swasheck: a table with `dept_1` through `dept_20` very strongly indicates a wrong design.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seriously questioning the design of the database... but maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
WHERE Dept_1 = 'ACCOUNTING'
  AND Dept_2 = 'ACCOUNTING'
  AND Dept_3 = 'ACCOUNTING'
  ... ad nauseum
  AND Dept_19 = 'ACCOUNTING'
  AND Dept_20 = 'ACCOUNTING'
```

Comment: Ugh indeed. The question seems to be more about getting around not having to type all of this out.

Comment: Well you only have to do it once and it will take a couple of minutes.  Is this used in a lot of places or something?  You could use a stored procedure and pass in the department, so you only have this ugly logic in one location.

Comment: Other approches will require even more typing, like using a set of `UNION`-ed queries for the `'ACCOUNTING' = ALL (...)` construct. This one is the shortest.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way may be to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table
 WHERE dept_1 = 'ACCOUNTING'
   AND dept_2 = 'ACCOUNTING'
   AND dept_3 = 'ACCOUNTING'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table
 WHERE dept_1 = 'ACCOUNTING'
    OR dept_2 = 'ACCOUNTING'
    OR dept_3 = 'ACCOUNTING'
```

It depends on if you want to grab the data where all 3 fields have the same value, or whether you want to grab the data when at least 1 of the fields matches.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to user the shorter version:

```
select *
from table
where 'ACCOUNTING' in (dept_1, dept_2, dept_3, . . . )
```

If you need for all the fields to be the same, then use a where clause with ANDs.

However, you might want to redesign the database to have a table with a separate row for each department.